# Rails 3 Drop Down Index Page Filter Sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

I am using Rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2. I have a storefront listing several products and I want to give users the ability to filter the products by `dept_type`. `dept_type` is a attribute of products and not a separate model. I have the following in my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEPT_TYPES = ["Baby","Beauty", "Household", "Pets"]
```

My controller:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title= "Home"
    if Product.all.collect(&:dept) == (params[:dept])
      @products= Product.send(params[:dept])
    else
      @products = Product.order(:premium)
    end
  end
```

In my view:

```
<%= select("dept", "dept_type", Product.all.collect(&:dept)) %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    ...
  <%end%>
```

When I load the page I have the dropdown with all the `DEPT_TYPES` options but when I select one nothing happens. What do I need to do to get the page to update and filter for only the selected dept?

Answer (score 2):

I would use ajax on the select and UJS to change the content, loaded from a partial.

e.g.

```
#/railsapp/app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def index
  @title= "Home"
  if Product.all.collect(&:dept_type) == (params[:dept])
    @products= Product.send(params[:dept])
  else
    @products = Product.order(:premium)
  end 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.js # index.js.erb
    format.json { render json: @products }
  end 
end
```

In your view

```
#/railsapp/app/views/products/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag('products', :remote => true) do %>
  <%= select_tag "dept", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, "id", "dept_type"),  { :include_blank => true , :class => "product_select"} %>
<% end %>

<div id="products_list"></div>
```

Then add the javascript (coffeescript in this case)

```
#/railsapp/app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee
$(document).ready ->
  $(".product_select").on "change", ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/products"
      type: "GET"
      dataType: "script"
      data:
        dept_type: $(".product_select").val()
```

So the coffeescript is making an ajax request to the index action of the products controller on change of the select box.  The controller will render the UJS template because the dataType is script.  Now for the UJS

```
#/railsapp/app/views/products/index.js.erb
$("#products_list").html('<%= j render("product_list") %>').fadeIn('slow');
```

This is just calling a javascript escaped render on the partial product_list, which includes:

```
#/railsapp/app/views/products/_product_list.html.erb
<%- @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
<% end %>
```

So now you'll have a select box which renders html on page load, javascript on ajax request to determine the correct department, and swaps out the list when you change your selection from the drop down.

Comment: First off thanks for the help and wealth of information. When i follow your suggestions i get this error: "undefined method `dept_type' for #<Product:0x47e9830>" pointing to this line of code:5:   <%= select_tag "dept", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, "id", "dept_type"),  { :include_blank => true , :class => "product_select"} %> any suggestions on how to address that? am i better creating a separate model for dept_types and the set products as having many dept_types and dept_type as belonging to products?